# neural network find best hyperameters or architecture first

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm implementing my first neural network for images classification.

I would like to know if i should start to find best hyperparameters first and then try to modify my neural network architecture (e.g number of layer, dropout...) or architecture then hyperameters?

Comment: Just "play" with every possible hyper-parameter to see how they affect different models, datasets, optimization algorithms. Once you feel that you have acquired enough confidence (after at least a few months) read about Bayesian hyper-parameter optimization. + tensorboard in TF2 now allows (relatively easy) to log your attempts for different hyper-parameter values. To go through [tutorials](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/docs/r2) on this can be a good thing to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is as always : it depends

**What are you trying to achieve?**
If you're hoping to make the worlds best image classifier by trial and error then you might want to ask yourself if you think you have more compute available than the people who have already done this. For a really good classifier there are several ones that come with tensorflow/keras and can be easily implemented. If you're goofing around and learning the coding then I'd recommend different architectures because that's going to teach you more functions. If you have a dataset you don't think existing solutions will be good at analysing and genuinely need the best network to solve classify them then unfortunately it still depends...

**How to decide:**
Firstly decide on the rough order of magnitude for your overall parameter count (the literal number of parameters your model has). For a given number of parameters, architecture is likely to produce the biggest difference in results between representative hyperparameter choices (don't choke your network down to a single neuron in the middle and expect it to be representative of that architecture).
Its important to compare the rough performance per parameter so you're not giving an edge to the networks with greater overfitting capacity. You don't need to use all your training data or even train to completion, mostly you'll find the better networks learn faster and finish better (**mostly**). In the past I've done grid searches with multiple trials at each point using significantly reduced data then optimised the architecture with the most potential by considering the gradients of the grid search. Fun fact: with sufficient time you can use gradient descent methods on hyperparameters to find local minima. You might well find that there are many similarly top performing models, all of which should you can tune until a clear winner emerges.

Answer (score 2):

First you should decide for an architecture and then play around with the hyperparameters. To compare different hyperparameters it is important to have the same base (architecture).

Of course you can also play around with the architecture (layers, nodes,...).But I think here it is easier to search for an architecture online, because often the same or a similar problem yet have been solved or described in a tutorial/blog.

The dropout is also a (training-)hyperparameter and not part of the architecture!